# How to render "&" operator sign in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

On my main page, I get "Account Set Up `&amp;`  Goal Setting" from API. I want to render a string like "Account Set Up & Goal Setting". but render like "Account Set Up `&amp;`  Goal Setting" in MVC, How i can fix that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are rending `&amp;` as a text not render as an html.
try the following code i hope this will help you.

Use `Html.Raw("Account Set Up &amp; Goal Setting")`

Comment: Mr. @Faraz You are legend.